# have to enter full path everytime

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run an executable via the cli, like so:

```
phpunit DefaultTest
```

but i get "command not found"
so i have to do:

```
/usr/lib/php/bin/phpunit DefaultTest
```

which works, how do i set it so i only have to use the executable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to append /usr/lib/php/bin to your $PATH environment variable.  The best way to do this is to edit .bashrc or .profile and add /usr/lib/php/bin at the end of the $PATH like in the example below.

Example:

```
.profile:

...
...
PATH="/usr/lib/php/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Your example adds it at the beginning.

Comment: great thanks, that worked. which is better .bashrc or .profile?

Comment: Ignacio: You're correct.  You can do this instead, then:

    PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/php/bin"

:)

Comment: mononym: .profile will work just fine, though if you have a .bash_profile as well, then if you're using bash, bash will favor .bash_profile over .profile AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can also symlink to a place in the standard path. If you need to execute it outside of shell or if it had to be available for all users

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/php/bin/phpunit /usr/local/bin
```

`/usr/local/bin` is in the path and is the common location of user installed binaries, so its contents are available for execution systemwide.

Comment: Not really an option, symlinking creates a mess. Basically the only viable solution is altering $PATH

Comment: I didn't agree. symlinking *beyond /usr/local* is completly natural way to install system-wide and IMHO is safer than add directories to the global path. As I said for system wide setups.